# Camera/Photo Library permission to upload image inside SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

My app uses SFSafariViewController and eventually the user will upload some images.

Should I add camera/photo library permission?

Answer (score 0):

yes. If your app does not have camera / photo library permissions, `SFSafariViewController` will not be able to access your photos.

Comment: nope, once time you used safaricontroller to access camera, you will get the request permission popup